# SolrNet with multiple solr instances configuration/instantiation with Windsor Container

Tags: solr, castle-windsor, solrnet

We're running a multi-tenant website (multiple hosts, different configs for each host, but one application) where every customer on every request could get routed to client-specific data bases and solr instances. So, depending on which url is mapped to the application, different connection strings will be provided for each request. This works well for normal databases where IConnectionProvider would provide a different connection string on each request depending on the hostname. We're using SolrNet for our text indexing and will have multiple instances running for the different hosts. Presently the SolrNet facility for Castle Windsor gets registered once with a solrUrl at configuration time. We want to be able to resolve an instance of SolrNet on every request with a different solrUrl depending on the tenant/host configuration. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [multi-core / multi-instance support in the SolrNet Windsor facility](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/MultiCoreAccess#With_Windsor_facility), then use a [IHandlerSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153418/what-is-the-best-practice-to-implement-multi-tenancy-in-asp-net-mvc-using-castle) to select the appropriate `ISolrOperations<T>` depending on tenant/host config.

Comment: Most links are dead. :(

Comment: Any examples for this with Unity? Here it uses different documents, while my requirement is to switch solr servers but query the same document type: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Multi-core-instance.md.