# How to resolve runtime dependencies in castle windsor for C#

Tags: c#-4.0, castle-windsor

I have a specific scenario here where I need to pass the connection string based on the user, because users may be mapped to the different databases based on his/her enterprise.

This is the code I use to resolve the dependency with a static variable:

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
    container.Register(
        Component.For<IUserRepository>()
                 .ImplementedBy(typeof(IKS.Dare.Optimix.Repository.EntityFramework.UserModule.UserRepository))
                 .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("connectionString", DatabaseSettings.DefaultConnectionString))
    );
}
```

Because this `DefaultConnectionString` is supposed to be a dynamic one, I don't want to lock this variable to make it thread safe, as this would degrade the performance. I would want a way so that I can deal with such situation.

Possible consideration which can be that we can give a session, which can be applied as follows:

```
DynamicParameters((k, d) => d["connectionString"] = Session["connectionString"])
```

But this is in a different project which doesn't utilize any web component, it's just an installer project which is basically designed for resolving the dependencies only.

My Generic repository looks like following

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
        private const string IsActive = "IsActive", DbContext = "dbContext", EntityPropertyName = "Entity";

        private string connectionString = String.Empty, provider = String.Empty;

        public GenericRepository(string connectionString, string provider)
        {
            this.connectionString = connectionString;
            this.provider = provider;
        }
        public int Count()
        {
            string tableName = typeof(T).Name;
            string query = SqlQueryConstants.SelectCount + SqlQueryConstants.Space + tableName;
            int count = DbHelper.ExecuteScalar<int>(query: query, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.Text, connectionString: connectionString, provider: provider, parameters: null);
            return count;
        }
}
```

DBHelper class looks like follows

```
public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string query, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            IList<DbParameter> parameters = null, int? timeout = null, string connectionString = "", string provider = "")
        {
            using (var connection = CreateDbConnection(connectionString, provider))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (DbCommand command = CreateDbCommand(sqlQuery: query, parameters: parameters,
                                                connection: connection, commandType: commandType, timeout: timeout))
                {
                    return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }

        public static DbParameter CreateParameter<TValue>(string name, TValue value, DbType dbType,
            ParameterDirection parameterDirection = ParameterDirection.Input, string provider = "")
        {
            DbParameter param = CreateDbProviderFactory(provider).CreateParameter();
            param.Value = value;
            param.ParameterName = name;
            param.DbType = dbType;
            param.Direction = parameterDirection;
            return param;
        }


        public static DbConnection CreateDbConnection()
        {
            return CreateDbConnection(String.Empty, String.Empty);
        }

        public static DbConnection CreateDbConnection(string connectionString = "", string provider = "")
        {
            DbConnection connection = null;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(provider))
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(DatabaseSettings.DefaultProvider))
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("provider");
                else
                    provider = DatabaseSettings.DefaultProvider;
            }
            connection = CreateDbProviderFactory(provider).CreateConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            return connection;
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note : I couldn't edit steven's answer.
[EDIT] To make it more clear it can be implemented as:

Here controller is inherited from BaseController

```
public class UserController : BaseController
    {
        //
        // GET: /Index/
        private IUserRepository userRepository;

        public UserController(IUserRepository userRepository)
            : base(userRepository)
        {
            this.userRepository = userRepository;
        }
}
```

and BaseController is inherited from Controller where in the database settings are being set in the constructor of Base controller so that we don't need to set it everywhere

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public BaseController(IUserRepository userRepository)
        {
            userRepository.connectionStringProvider.Provider = WebUtilities.CurrentUserData.Provider;
            userRepository.connectionStringProvider.ConnectionString = WebUtilities.CurrentUserData.ConnectionString;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Runtime data should [not be injected into the constructor of your components](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Comment: @Steven, I understand your point but I've a situation where my repositories are dependent on variable connection string and providers. Can you suggest me a better approach?

Comment: First of all, since you will have possibly many repositories that require a connection, hide the connection string behind an `IConnectionFactory` or `IDbContextProvider` abstraction (depending on your needs of course). With such abstraction it becomes trivial to create an adapter implementation that gets the proper connection string at runtime and either creates a new SqlConnection or DbContext. The repository than calls `connectionFactory.CreateConnection()` or `dbContextProvider.CurrentContext`.

Comment: I am sorry but I couldn't understand you properly, I've a connectionFactory  which basically requires 'provider info', In that also if I pass provider dynamically then also it remains a dynamic dependency for IConnectionFactory.

Can you elaborate more with an example? Thank you

Comment: Can you update your question and provide examples of what you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, the connection string is runtime data, you should not use it to construct your application components, as is described in [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99). So as the article advices, you should hide the connection string behind a provider abstraction. For instance:

```
public interface IConnectionStringProvider {
    string ConnectionString { get; }
}
```

This way your repositories can depend on `IConnectionStringProvider` and can call `IConnectionStringProvider.ConnectionString` at runtime:

```
public int Count()
{
    string tableName = typeof(T).Name;
    string query = SqlQueryConstants.SelectCount + SqlQueryConstants.Space + tableName;
    return DbHelper.ExecuteScalar<int>(
        this.connectionStringProvider.ConnectionString, 
        provider: provider, parameters: null);
}
```

It will be trivial to create an `IConnectionStringProvider` to will get the correct connection string for you:

```
class DatabaseConnectionStringProvider : IConnectionStringProvider
{
    public string ConnectionString => Session["connectionString"];
}
```

Since this clas depends on application-specifics (the ASP.NET session in this case), the class should not be part of the application's core logic. Instead, this adapter should live in the application's start up path (a.k.a. the composition root, the place where you configure your container).

You might even want to consider not passing along the `IConnectionStringProvider` into your repositories, but instead create an abstraction that will create a connection itself. This will hide the fact that there is a connection string completely.

Comment: But the situation is that my repositories reside in a different layer which doesn't directly interact with Session. Can you please make it little more clear, I think it would be a great help. Even I don't want to use the dynamic dependencies.

Comment: @AjaySuwalka: That's the beauty of abstractions. You can place the abstraction in a different assembly than you place its implementation. As a matter of fact, the implementation should be part of your [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). Since you composition root is application specific, you can depend on anything that is specific to that application, such as the session.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is multi tenancy.  You can google "[castle windsor multi tenancy](https://www.google.com/search?q=castle%20windsor%20multi%20tenancy)" and find a number of useful articles.

Here's a similar [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153418/what-is-the-best-practice-to-implement-multi-tenancy-in-asp-net-mvc-using-castle) that links to some good articles on Windsor and multi tenancy.  In particular, look into Windsor's [IHandlerSelector](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/handler-selectors.md) interface.

Comment: I appreciate that you tried to answer my question, But I couldn't relate my situation with the answers you provided. Thank you.